# How to completely surrender to my deity?

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, krishna, shakti

Hey guys I want to know what it mean to completely surrender to God
Right now my life is going the completely wrong way so pls listen to my problems and pls give me some solutions

Everything is going wrong in my life I want to be an actor but my family isn't allowing me so I'm studying for 7-8 hrs daily even if I don't want to so that I can get into a good college in big city like Delhi and Mumbai so I can pursue my acting career
My social, sex and love life is completely messed up It feels like I'm in prison whenever I'm surrounded by people especially if girls it feels like I'm going to finish a war my love and sex life are completely 0 whenever I see my friends with their GF's it makes me sad that why don't I have this kind of relationship with someone(I know I'm being materialistic here and some people here can find this wrong I tried to control my desires but failed)

Also, some people may not see this as a problem but for me, my height is a huge problem it's even shorter than average I feel embarrassed in public I'm praying for years for my height
to increase
So tell me how am I supposed to surrender to God in these situation completely pls

Comment: In simple terms when one says to completely surrender to god it basically means whether there are ups or downs in life just remain stable, don't get bogged down by the situations, nothing is permanent in this world whether it's pleasure or pain, it will come and it will go. Usually such incidents are there to teach you something only if you are willing to learn with open mind. Let things happen the way they are happening do not react but respond. Don't expect anything from anyone even if they are your close ones, because expectations is a major source of ones miseries.

Comment: I think you must be in your teens, There is a lot of ups and downs, So just keep chanting your ishta deva's name, By this you can have a control on yourself and be devoted to God too

Comment: @Just_Do_It I know it means trusting the deity but whenever I'm in wrong mood I started doubting my deity, my mind automatically start asking things like what's the points of worshipping the problem just keep getting increased

Comment: @Shashaank yes you're right in some months I'm gosling start my last teenage year in some months and I don't want it to be as bad as these last two years

Comment: I too am in my teens and I can understand you very well :-) So Just cling to your Istha Deva, Everything would be better soon :-)

Comment: @Shashaank    Hope so, thnks, for understanding me

Comment: @devibhakt you're comments always give me a different type of smile  thnks